# Join tables with comma separated string (using WHERE)

Tags: sql, join, presto

I have two tables, lets call it table A and table B. They looks like:

```
A.col1        A.colX            B.colY
1             123               123
2             234, 123          234     
3             2, 52352          2
                                52352
```

What I have to do is to `JOIN` them, most probably using `WHERE`, because non-equi join is not supported in my environment. I have the problem with table `A`, where numbers are as string. I tried solution with:

```
SELECT... 
FROM A, B
WHERE A.colX LIKE concat('%', B.colY, '%')
```

but it doesn't work correctly as for example value `2` from `B.colY` appears in every string from table `A.colX`.

At the end example what i want to achieve:

```
          output
1         123 -------> 123
2         234, 123 --> 234
1         234, 123 --> 123
3         2, 52352 --> 2
3         2, 52352 --> 52352
```

Do you have any ideas for that ?

Comment: First of all - it is definitely bad table schema design. Instead of comma separated lists like `234, 123` in `A.colX` it should be related table holding these values in different records `234`, `123` (and a foreign key back to table A, of course) . Having that separate table you're getting rid of complicated join conditions.

Comment: Data type for B.colY?

Comment: I agree with you, but this data come from uploaded excel file into database. Those two tables are separate spreadsheets from excel.

Comment: data type is different for both columns but I am converting it using Cast() (from bigint to varchar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where (',' || replace(A.colX,' ','') || ',') LIKE ('%,' || B.colY || ',%')
```

I.e. remove the spaces from A.colX, add a comma before and after, then do `like` with B.colY also with commas.

`||` is concatenation the ANSI SQL way, some products use `CONCAT` or `+` instead.

Comment: Looks like it works like a charm :) One comment for your code, in replace fucntion there should be: replace(A.colX,',' ,''), one sign too much in your code. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Thanks for notifying me!

Comment: After short investigation i found that it doesn't work correctly. Values from comma-separated strings are missing. Any solution for that ?

Comment: Odd. It works for me. Did you adjust the syntax to fit dbms?

Comment: Got it! you have changed your replace funciton again. I had it like 2 posts above. Now duplicate values from strings are in my output :) Thank you again :)

Comment: Put both the ',' || replace(A.colX,' ','') || ',' and '%,' || B.colY || ',%' in the select list, and remove the LIKE from the WHERE clause, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can split() the string into an array, then unnest() that to produce separate rows for each part, then perform a regular join.

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest